# Phonegap global $.ajax retry on timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I use Backbone.js for my Phonegap application, if there is a bad internet connection a timeout often occurs, I need a way to catch this timeout and retry infinite times.

I need either a way to set some kind of timeout function globally with $.ajaxSetup or a Backbone.js way.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please edit your existing question if you want to add more details to it. Don't duplicate it.